# Continuous data streaming Arduino to Python

Tags: python, arduino

I am trying to get a Python GUI window using [Tkinter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) to continuously display data streaming from an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) board acting as a voltmeter. With the code I've got, the window will display one data point, and once the window gets closed, a new window opens up with the next available data point. Here's the code I've been using:

```
import serial
from Tkinter import *
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem621')
ser.baudrate = 9600
while 1 == 1:
    reading = ser.readline()
    root = Tk()
    w = Label(root, text = reading)
    w.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I'm using a [MacBook Pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro), and the [pySerial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/) package for my serial communications. How do I get the window to refresh itself?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're creating a new root for every loop iteration. Try this code:

```
import serial
from Tkinter import *
from time import sleep
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem621')
ser.baudrate = 9600

def update():
    while 1:
        reading.set(ser.readline())
        root.update()
        sleep(1)

root=Tk()
reading = StringVar()

w = Label(root, textvariable = reading)
w.pack()

root.after(1,update)    
root.mainloop()
```

This sets up the "mainloop" to call the "update" function after a millisecond and uses a reference to the variable "reading" rather that the actual value of it, allowing it to be updated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helped quite a bit, thanks. The only thing that needed to be done differently was to define the variable 'reading' so I did that after defining 'update' and the code works exactly how I was expecting it to.